# Как вставить массив в массив на языке С++?

Tags: c++

У меня есть 2 массива вида:

```
int b1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int b2[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};
```

Я хочу вставить эти массивы в другой массив

```
int ary[2][5] = {b1,b2};
```

Но я получаю ошибку значение типа "int*" нельзя использовать для инициализации типа int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С++ также как и в Си элементы многомерных массивов хранятся в памяти последовательно. Но не факт, что два одномерных массива будут находится рядом друг с дружкой. Чтобы получить новый двумерный массив с элементами двух исходных, придётся их содержимое копировать.

```
int ary[2][5];
memcpy(ary[0], b1, sizeof(b1));
memcpy(ary[1], b2, sizeof(b2));
```

Пример работы: https://ideone.com/Cd0oqS

Конструкция sizeof вычисляет количество байтов, сколько занимает каждый из массивов.

Нужно учесть, что с помощью функции memcpy из Си в коде на С++ можно копировать только [POD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) типы данных. `int` к таковым относится.

Comment: Или через `std::copy`, чтобы нормально работало с произвольными классами.

Answer (score 1):

В языке С++ в тех ситуациях, когда вам нужен обычный С-массив, рекомендуется пользоваться его аналогом - классом `std::array`. Класс `std::array` в том числе как раз и предназначен для решения проблемы некопируемости С-массивов

```
std::array<int, 5> b1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::array<int, 5> b2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 2> ary = { b1, b2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь получить рваный массив, то следует использовать массив указателей, а не двумерный массив. При этом данные не копируется, а  в массиве сохраняется ссылка на те же данные.

https://ideone.com/8AjUUn

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int b1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int b2[5] = {6,7,8,9,10};

  int *a[2] = {b1, b2};

  for (size_t q=0; q<2; ++q)
  {
    for (size_t w=0; w<5; ++w)
      cout << a[q][w] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AnT, убрал. Осталось от [экспериментов со скобками](https://ideone.com/ophliX).